# I need help to identify the front that was used on this sign? Can anyone help?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

[image]

I am looking for the font that was used on this sign

Comment: You can start by looking through the [Script category on dafont.com](https://www.dafont.com/mtheme.php?id=6&text=Lady+Slipper&fpp=200&psize=l) to see if it's a free font.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly drawn from a sample: it's rather like [Single Ladies](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/scoothtype/single-ladies/) (which is not free but hardly expensive)

[image: Sample image]